# Mongoose save() not being processed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

Pardon the noob question, but can anyone spot what am I doing wrong here? For some reason it looks like it does not go through the save() hook, as nothing is printed to the console...

```
router.post('/users', (req, res, err) => {
  var user = new User(req.body);

  user.save().then(function(user) {
    console.log('user save()');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.send(err);
  });
});
```

When I'm printing to the console the `user` var, before the `save()`, I get to see the right data.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Resolved.

I've added the `auto` flag to `_id` in my schema, as the error was that no _id was provided/generated at `insert()` time.

```
_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    auto: true,
  },
```

Comment: Does it catch any error? As a side note you are shadowing the user.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are connected to the database? Are other MongoDB/Mongoose functions working?

Comment: @MikaS All the `.get()` requests work just fine, using `.find()` in the db.

Comment: @AlexBlex No no errors either. Shadowing because I'm reusing the `user` name?

Comment: My suggestion then is to use `mongoose.set('debug', true);` to see what Mongoose does in the background. You should also rename the user and err variables in the then and catch. You already have variables with those names further up. Shouldn't matter in this particular case though.

Comment: @MikaS Thanks for the suggestions. `debug` was already set and spits nothing. Renamed the vars as well, no change. Still does not seem to go through the `save()`...

Comment: What do you have in http response? like in `curl -v http://your_app/users --data "{your user json}"`?  try to `return user.save()` in your route.

Comment: @AlexBlex Interesting.... I get this error: `{"message":"document must have an _id before saving","name":"MongooseError"}` -- I thought an `_id` would be generated automatically if not provided..

Comment: cool, so the mystery's solved. `then()` function was not invoked because `catch()` was.

Comment: @AlexBlex Yeah, sort of... Now I'm wondering why it's not generating the _id automatically. Should I be generating it myself?

Comment: fair enough. do some research in this direction. I am pretty sure you can find the answer on SO.

Comment: id should be generated automatically. That should happen when you use `new User`. I assume User is a registered schema and not just a constructor function? Also double check that you don't mess with the id in the schema.